# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:org/openxmlformats/shemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTWorkbook.Factory

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm getting this error java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:org/openxmlformats/shemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTWorkbook.Factory,

I've poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar, poi-5.2.3.jar and poi-ooxml-full-5.2.3.jar

I tried changing the versions also.

Comment: You have an inconsistent or incompatible dependency somewhere that is trying to reference a field which doesn't exist in the actual class on your classpath.